# Instamojo Payment Gateway

Tags: php, laravel, instamojo

I want to integrate instamojo in my app. But I'm backend developer. Can any one help me how to integrate instamojo with andoid. I want to integrate it into laravel.

So can any one tell me that how to generate orderID and further implementation.

Comment: Have you done any research, or coding so far?

Comment: yes, i have done integration for web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install `Instamojo` php package

```
composer require instamojo/instamojo-php
```

More info [packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/instamojo/instamojo-php) Or [Steps to install with laravel](https://www.tutsmake.com/how-to-integrate-instamojo-payment-gateway-in-laravel-5-7/)

Comment: I have done one web, now I have to create for api. which will be used by android. So what and how to do?